# Allow method to accept an :id param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have created a method called verify in a controller (events_controller.rb), and I want to allow that page (verify.html.erb) to accept an object (@event), and show of that objects parameters. I'm creating a show page in essence, but I need to build some special logic into this page that I don't want to build into the show page. I have created the route, but I still get an error when I tell it to find an Event by params[:id]. The actual url it is going to is /verify.(event :id) and I believe it should be routing to events/verify/(event :id).

My error

```
Couldn't find Event without an ID.
```

routes.rb

```
get "verify", to: 'events#verify'
resources :events
```

events_controller.rb

```
def verify
@event = Event.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # verify.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @event }
end
end
```

Thanks Stack!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
get "verify/:id", to: 'events#verify', as: "verify"
```

in browser go to url for example:

`localhost:3000/verify/1`

Comment: This worked perfectly! Could you explain what is happening here? I read through the rails guide for routing, but it did not help any. Thanks again!

Comment: well.. nothing magic, by saying `get "verify/:id"` means that after `/verify/` will be a param that you send, in your case id ':id'.

Comment: also you can name your param as you want, for ex: `get "verify/:my_fancy_id"` and this param will be sent(`:my_fancy_id => 1`) to controller where you'll write `@event = Event.find(params[:my_fancy_id])`

Comment: would've tell you more but we can not chat yet on SO as you have a small reputation.

Comment: Interesting! Yeah, I got some reputation taken away for a previous question. I revised it, but still no one responded after they moved the question to "closed", and I don't know how to reopen it haha. I'm a SO new comer.